# CMake toolchain not finding standard C/C++ includes or libraries

Tags: c++, c, cmake, toolchain

I'm trying to write my CMakeLists.txt files in a way that can be compiled with and without toolchain support, but I am running into compile and linker issues where common C/C++ libraries aren't getting found or linked.
After reading [CMake toolchain documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) the only configuration option I could see that would control how the standard libraries are found is the `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable.
I happen to be using a TI toolchain so I specify a path `set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "C:/ti/ccs1031/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_20.2.4.LTS")`

When I compile without specifying a toolchain file everything works fine and I get the compiled target for the host system.

```sh
> cmake -E make_directory build && \
> cmake -E chdir build cmake .. && \
> cmake --build build --config Debug
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/src/cmake-toolchain-example/build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/src/cmake-toolchain-example/CMakeLists.txt
  example.vcxproj -> C:\src\cmake-toolchain-example\build\Debug\example.exe
  Building Custom Rule C:/src/cmake-toolchain-example/CMakeLists.txt
```

However, when I try compiling with the toolchain that uses the TI toolchain I get errors related to standard library.

```sh
> cmake -E make_directory ../build && \
> cmake -E chdir ../build cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja" --toolchain cmake/Toolchains/ti-cgt-toolchain.cmake ../cmake-toolchain-example && \
> cmake --build ../build --config Debug
-- Using toolchain file: cmake/Toolchains/ti-cgt-toolchain.cmake
-- Using toolchain file: C:/src/cmake-toolchain-example/cmake/Toolchains/ti-cgt-toolchain.cmake
-- The C compiler identification is TI 20.2.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is TI 20.2.4
-- Found Eclipse version 4.14 ()
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - failed
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - failed
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/src/build
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\example.dir\main.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.obj
C:\ti\ccs1031\ccs\tools\compiler\ti-cgt-arm_20.2.4.LTS\bin\armcl.exe --compile_only --cpp_file=C:\src\cmake-toolchain-example\main.cpp    --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency=CMakeFiles\example.dir\main.cpp.obj.d --output_file=CMakeFiles\example.dir\main.cpp.obj
"C:\src\cmake-toolchain-example\main.cpp", line 1: fatal error: could not open source file "iostream" (no directories in search list)
1 catastrophic error detected in the compilation of "C:\src\cmake-toolchain-example\main.cpp".
Compilation terminated.

>> Compilation failure
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I think I am missing something obvious when it comes to crosscompiling that is automatically handled when using the default CMake generators.
When using toolchain files, does one have to manually add the `include/`, `lib/`, etc to their respective CMake variables?
I guess I was under the impression that the `CMAKE_SYSROOT` along with other CMake variables such as `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`, `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH`, etc use some sane defaults that work for most toolchains.
The standard C/C++ includes for my toolchain are located at `C:\ti\ccs1031\ccs\tools\compiler\ti-cgt-arm_20.2.4.LTS\include` and there is a `libc.a` that is available at `C:\ti\ccs1031\ccs\tools\compiler\ti-cgt-arm_20.2.4.LTS\lib`.
However, since I don't have to specify that standard stuff in my CMakeLists.txt when not using a toolchain file I would like to not specify it when I am using a toolchain file.

What else is needed in the toolchain file to help resolve C/C++ standard library issues like this?
I will provide a simple git repo to demonstrate this issue located [here](https://github.com/erichschroeter/cmake-toolchain-example).

*EDIT*:
I came across [this e2e forum post](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000-microcontrollers-group/c2000/f/c2000-microcontrollers-forum/892614/compiler-tms320f28335-cmake-project-for-c2000-compiler) that was pretty helpful.

Comment: "I was under the impression that the `CMAKE_SYSROOT` along with other CMake variables such as `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`, `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH`, etc use some sane defaults that work for most toolchains." - Have you read documentation for any of that variables? E.g. [CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH.html) only affects on `find_library` call. BTW, you set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS` exactly for prevent CMake to try to compile a test code, which helps CMake to determine features of the compiler...

Comment: You definitely could try to add include directories via variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and libraries via `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable. Or even via `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT` variable, as noted in [that mail](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2019-February/069083.html).

Comment: Ya, I had to bypass with `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS` due to the reason they specify in [that link you provided](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2019-February/069083.html); cmake config just fails otherwise. I'll try playing around with `include_directories` and the `FLAGS` variables.